# Replacing object's properties with properties from another object in JavaScript, without libraries

Tags: javascript, object, properties, default, extend

I've been using jQuery.extend to replace default properties like this

```
var Car = function(options){
    var defaultOptions = {
        color: "hotpink",
        seats: {
            material: "fur",
            color: "black",
            count: 4
        },
        wheels: 4
    }
    this.options = $.extend(true,{},defaultOptions,options); 
}

var myCar = new Car({
    color: "blue",
    seats: {
        count: 2,
        material: "leather"
    }
});

alert(myCar.options.color); // "blue"
alert(myCar.options.seats.color); // "black"
alert(myCar.options.seats.count); // 2
```

While it works great, I'd like to know the best way to achieve similar results without any libraries. I just want to define some default settings in a function and replace them with settings from arguments, would be an overkill to include a library every time I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it's just a recursive use of [`for..in`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4). You can see the full source of jQuery's implementation [in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L277) (the line number on that will rot over time, but it's likely to remain in `core.js`).

Here's a very basic off-the-cuff:

```
function deepCopy(src, dest) {
    var name,
        value,
        isArray,
        toString = Object.prototype.toString;

    // If no `dest`, create one
    if (!dest) {
        isArray = toString.call(src) === "[object Array]";
        if (isArray) {
            dest = [];
            dest.length = src.length;
        }
        else { // You could have lots of checks here for other types of objects
            dest = {};
        }
    }

    // Loop through the props
    for (name in src) {
        // If you don't want to copy inherited properties, add a `hasOwnProperty` check here
        // In our case, we only do that for arrays, but it depends on your needs
        if (!isArray || src.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            value = src[name];
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                // Recurse
                value = deepCopy(value);
            }
            dest[name] = value;
        }
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: If the OP wants to keep the API, then jQuery is a good start but if the OP is prepared to change (simplify) the API a purpose built extend can be shorter, more efficient and more robust (e.g. the jQuery *isPlainObject* is pretty ordinary and not necessary, nor is *isFunction* or *isArray*).

Comment: What RobG said, the jQuery implementation seems like a quite a bit of code. I was wondering if there's any workarounds, or other ways to tackle this issue.

Comment: I'm trying to make an easy-to-use, independent code snippet that's basically just one function with a few methods inside. Kind of like a jQuery plugin, but without dependency on jQuery.

I'd want to let the user define all the options in a single object for the sake of readable code, but I want to define default values for everything so the user doesn't need to change anything if he's happy with the default looks and functionality.

Comment: @user1463028: I was just referring to jQuery's as an example of a fairly thoroughly-done version that's survived a lot of use. The fundamental point is that it's just a recursive use of `for..in`. I've added a very basic one, but why not use something that's been thoroughly tested instead? Yes, it will take a bit more time to understand and unpick, but... :-) Best,

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate jQuery's api "extend", just like upstairs said. I think there's no better way to manage to do this. So, I think jQuery's api is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 it was introduced spread operator.

```
var Car = function(options){
    var defaultOptions = {
        color: "hotpink",
        seats: {
            material: "fur",
            color: "black",
            count: 4
        },
        wheels: 4
    }
    this.options = {...defaultOptions, ...this.options};
}

var myCar = new Car({
    color: "blue",
    seats: {
        count: 2,
        material: "leather"
    }
});
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- [How do I merge two javascript objects together in ES6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852852/how-do-i-merge-two-javascript-objects-together-in-es6)
- Or you may use [`Object.assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121695/merge-two-objects-with-es6)