# (_.merge in ES6/ES7)Object.assign without overriding undefined values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

There is [_.merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965844/lodash-difference-between-extend-assign-and-merge?noredirect=1&lq=1) functionality in lodash. I want to achieve the same thing in ES6 or ES7.

Having this snippet:

```
Object.assign({}, {key: 2}, {key: undefined})
```

I want to receive `{key: 2}`. Currently I receive `{key: undefined}`

This is **NOT** a deep merge.

Is it possible? If yes then how to achieve that?

Comment: Note: this question does not cover my case with undefined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852852/surely-es6-must-have-a-way-to-merge-two-javascript-objects-together-what-is-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can take the second object, prune any values that are `undefined` and then use it in `Object.assign`

Comment: @vlaz is there native ES6 way to prune undefiend values from object?

Comment: Well, if you take ES5 with just a dash of ES6 then `arr.filter(x => typeof x !== "undefined" )`

Comment: gah, sorry, forgot it's an object: `Object.keys(obj).reduce(key => typeof obj[key] !== "undefined" ).reduce( (memo, key) => (memo[key] = obj[key]; memo), {})` admittedly, doesn't look as pretty when in one line but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Why does your object have undefined values in it? Just wondering.

Comment: @torazaburo very good bug catch. That was the issue in my case. I should not provide undefined values in the first place

Comment: "This is NOT a deep merge." How is this not a deep merge? It's simply a deep merge with slightly different behavior, and in my opinion, behavior that makes more sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't achieve that with a straight usage of `Object.assign`, because each next object will rewrite the same keys for prev merge. The only way, to filter your incoming objects with some hand-crafted function.

```
function filterObject(obj) {
    const ret = {};
    Object.keys(obj)
        .filter((key) => obj[key] !== undefined)
        .forEach((key) => ret[key] = obj[key]);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: you could also pass the predicate as an argument, so that it works like `Array.filter`

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `)` after `obj[key]`

Comment: @TechnoTim thnx, fixed

Comment: How to have the same logic within a `deepmerge` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can simply filter out the keys with `undefined` values before passing them to `Object.assign()`:

```js
const assign = (target, ...sources) =>
  Object.assign(target, ...sources.map(x =>
    Object.entries(x)
      .filter(([key, value]) => value !== undefined)
      .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (obj[key] = value, obj), {})
  ))

console.log(assign({}, {key: 2}, {key: undefined}))
```

Answer (score 5):

Write a little utility to remove undefined values:

```
function removeUndefined(obj) {
  for (let k in obj) if (obj[k] === undefined) delete obj[k];
  return obj;
}
```

Then

```
Object.assign({}, {key: 2}, removeUndefined({key: undefined}))
```

This seems preferable to writing your own `assign` with wired-in behavior to remove undefined values.

Comment: That approach mutates the incoming object and could make problems in some cases

Answer (score 2):

use lodash to omit nil values and then combine the two objects into one via spread

```
{ ...(omitBy({key: 2}, isNil)), ...(omitBy({key: undefined}, isNil))}
```

See more info on lodash here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15

Answer (score 1):

With ES2019/ES10's new object method, [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), Michał's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977764/2379762) can be updated:

```
const assign = (target, ...sources) =>
  Object.assign(target, ...sources.map(x =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(x)
        .filter(([key, value]) => value !== undefined)
    )
  ))

console.log(assign({}, {key: 2}, {key: undefined}))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the values and don't need an object, you could also use object destructuring:

```js
const input = { a: 0, b: "", c: false, d: null, e: undefined };
const { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6 } = input;
console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f);
// => 0, "", false, null, 5, 6
```

This will only override absent or undefined values.

I often use this for function argument default values like this:

```js
function f(options = {}) {
  const { foo = 42, bar } = options;
  console.log(foo, bar);
}

f();
// => 42, undefined

f({})
// => 42, undefined

f({ foo: 123 })
// => 123, undefined

f({ bar: 567 })
// => 42, 567

f({ foo: 123, bar: 567 })
// => 123, 567
```