# parameters from object passed in res.render()

Tags: node.js, express

I have an object (in real code there is more values inside):

req.session.params = {valueA: a, valueB: b, result: result}

I would like to pass its pairs to res.render() along the others. For now I'm doing:

```
res.render('mainView.ejs', {
        otherVal: x,
        valueA: a, 
        valueB: b, 
        result: result
      });
```

but is there a way to do that quicker? Something like:

```
res.render('mainView.ejs', {otherVal: x,
           {req.session.passedParams}
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
res.render('mainView.ejs', Object.assign({otherVal: x},req.session.passedParams));
```

or

```
res.render('mainView.ejs', {{otherVal: x},...req.session.passedParams});
```

PS: See [Surely ES6+ must have a way to merge two javascript objects together, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852852/surely-es6-must-have-a-way-to-merge-two-javascript-objects-together-what-is-it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash package to accomplish this easily

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var params = _.assign({otherVal: x}, req.session.passedParams);

console.log(params);
```

I hope this helps