# JS merge two objects doesnt works

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, lodash

I try to use the following to merge object which doesn't works,
what I need that if `this.options` have the property put it on `this.props` otherwise use the `this.props` defaults.

Any idea how I can merge it in a shorter way, I've more fields that are doing the same

```js
this.props!.hostName = this.options.hostName || this.props!.hostName;
this.props!.eventType = this.options.eventType || this.props!.eventType;
this.props!.eventTypeVersion = this.options.eventTypeVersion || this.props!.eventTypeVersion;
this.props!.uri = this.options.uri || this.props!.uri;
```

i've tried the following which doesnt works

```js
this.props = Object.assign(this.props, this.options);
```

and also this

```js
this.props = Object.assign(this.options, this.props);
```

Comment: Does the `Object.assign()` throw an error?

Comment: @TasosBu - no that I see ...

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852852/how-do-i-merge-two-javascript-objects-together-in-es6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt, `Object.assign(this.props, this.options)` should work. If it doesn't that probably means that `this.options` has some falsy properties which you want to ignore. You can try filtering those out:

```
const truthyOptions = Object.entries(this.options)
    .filter(([k,v]) => v)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))

this.props = Object.assign(this.props, ...truthyOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator:

```
{...props, ...options}
```

OR

```
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(props)) {
  props[k] = options[k] || v
};
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as using the Object.assign()