# Merge two objects with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm sure this question has been asked before but I can't quite find the answer I'm looking for, so here goes:

I have two objects, as follows:

```
const response = {
  lat: -51.3303,
  lng: 0.39440
}

let item = {
  id: 'qwenhee-9763ae-lenfya',
  address: '14-22 Elder St, London, E1 6BT, UK'
}
```

I need to merge these together to form this:

```
item = {
  id: 'qwenhee-9763ae-lenfya',
  address: '14-22 Elder St, London, E1 6BT, UK',
  location: {
    lat: -51.3303,
    lng: 0.39440
  }
}
```

I know I could do it like this:

```
item.location = {}
item.location.lat = response.lat
item.location.lng = response.lng
```

However, I feel that this is not the best way to do it anymore, because ES6 introduced the cool destructuring/assignment stuff; I tried deep object merging but it's unfortunately not supported :( I also looked through some ramda functions but couldn't see anything that was applicable.

So what is the best way to merge these two objects using ES6?

Comment: *"ES6 introduced the cool destructuring/assignment stuff"* Which doesn't help at all with merging object properties.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` to merge them into a new object:

```js
const response = {
  lat: -51.3303,
  lng: 0.39440
}

const item = {
  id: 'qwenhee-9763ae-lenfya',
  address: '14-22 Elder St, London, E1 6BT, UK'
}

const newItem = Object.assign({}, item, { location: response });

console.log(newItem );
```

You can also use [object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which is a Stage 4 proposal for ECMAScript:

```js
const response = {
  lat: -51.3303,
  lng: 0.39440
}

const item = {
  id: 'qwenhee-9763ae-lenfya',
  address: '14-22 Elder St, London, E1 6BT, UK'
}

const newItem = { ...item, location: response }; // or { ...response } if you want to clone response as well

console.log(newItem );
```

Comment: Be careful if you do `const newItem = { ...item, location: response };`, because `location` property of `newItem` is a reference to `response` object. You'd better do it like `const newItem = { ...item, location: {...response} };` to avoid referencing and be safe.

Comment: `Object.assign`  works for me.. thanks.

Answer (score 75):

Another aproach is:

```
let result = { ...item, location: { ...response } }
```

But Object spread isn't [yet standardized](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

May also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926019/5341953

Comment: In this way, response saved as a pointer rather than a deep clone.  This should be the correct answer `let result = { ...item, location : {...response} }`