# Angular - Use map operations like merge, put and delete on a simple object

Tags: angular, dictionary

I have an object in angular 5, like this one:

```
public obj1 = {
    A: 5,
    B: false,
    C: 'c'
};
```

And another one:

```
public obj2 = {
    A: 10,
    E: true,
    D: 'd'
};
```

How can I merge these two object, or delete one of these object properties ?
I need to do `Map` operations over this simple object.

---

**Update:**

I need a way, if there is, to cast this simple object into a `Map`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
public obj1 = {
    A: 5,
    B: false,
    C: 'c'
};

public obj2 = {
    A: 10,
    E: true,
    D: 'd'
};

const newItem = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```

See the first answer of this question.

[Merge two objects with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121695/merge-two-objects-with-es6)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19173457)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation, in the next time I will post the better answer, thanks again.

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your answer to improve it.

Comment: That is a good way to do merge, But is there a way to delete a property from this object.